# Apply tf.keras model to tensor of variable shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have a `tf.keras` model that takes as input a tensor of shape `(batch_size, )` and outputs another tensor of the same shape. The result at index `i` does not depend on any of the inputs at index `j != i`.

I would like to apply this model on tensors of any shape `(dim1, dim2, ..., dimn)`. In theory this should be possible, but in practice tensorflow refuses to process anything with an input shape of more than 1 dimension. What would be the most elegant work-around to bypass this? I've looked at `tf.map_fn` but this might get complicated when used recursively. Any simpler methods I'm overlooking?

Comment: How do you generalize the logic of "`i` does not depend on any inputs at `j != i`" to multi-dimensional case?

Comment: `i, j, ..., k` does not depend on `i', j', ... k'`. A simple example is the following: suppose you have a neural network that works on a sample of `(batch_size, )` , i.e. a vector. Then you can apply it to a matrix by simply applying it successively to all the columns. To a tensor by applying it to each matrix successively, ... I'm just trying to find a way to do this without getting too complicated.

Comment: Doesn't the expected shape of your input depend on the definition of the model? If you had a model for processing color images, then, such a model would expect four dimensions `(batch, height, width, channels)`. You could flatten your tensor `tf.reshape(t, [-1])`, but I cannot tell whether this is something you can do here.

Comment: You can see it as follows then. If you have such a model that processes images, and it expects four dimensions `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` then how do you get it to work on a dataset of size `(batch_size1, batch_size2, ... batch_sizen, height, width, channels)`? Is there a simple way to reshape to one batch dim --> apply the model --> reshape back to original dimensions? If so, please elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it like this:

```py
def apply_model(X: tf.Tensor, my_model: tf.keras.Model) -> tf.Tensor:
        """
        Apply a tf.keras.Model to a tensor of unknown dimensions.

        Args:
            X (tf.Tensor): The tensor containing the input.
            my_model (tf.keras.Model): The model you want to apply.

        Returns:
            tf.Tensor: A tensor of the same shape as X, where all values are
                a prediction by the model.
        """
        if len(X.shape) > 1:
            result = tf.stack(
                [apply_model(x) for x in tf.unstack(X, axis=-1)],
                axis=-1,
            )
        else:
            result = my_model(X)

        return result
```

Of course, you can generalize this to a case where the model takes an input of more than 1 dimension.